# How can I use the Top Bar setting of a UITableViewController in IB?

Tags: uitableview, user-interface, builder, navigationcontroller

I have a .xib with a controller, a `UITableViewController`. It contains a `UITableView`, which is controlled by the right .h, .m files and `IBOutlets`. All works fine, but I want a Navigation Bar on top of the view. Now I saw this setting in Interface Builder, which is in the Attributes window of the `UITableViewController`: "Top Bar". I set this to Navigation Bar, which nicely renders an empty navigation bar above the table view.

But I don't see it on my iPhone! How can I access this navigation bar, set its title and an edit button? Do I have to connect it to an outlet somewhere? I tried to add a navigation bar manually, but that doesn't work since its a `UITableView`.

Can someone help me out? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Top Bar" option in IB is only to *simulate* what your UI would look like with a Navigation Bar. To actually see a navigation bar, you'll have to embed your UIViewController within a UINavigationController.

To find out how that works, check out the "Navigation-based Application" template in Xcode and check this out: http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I never thought of that. I used "iPhone Application Development" by John Ray to build up my table-based application. It kinda covers the same thing, like in the tutorial you provided. I think I'll just wrap it all in a second view controller, which obviously will contain the navigation bar. Thanks for your help!